# Should you commit the typings folder for es6 projects when using vscode?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

So I have been using Visual Studio Code (vscode) when playing with some sample es6 projects.

My understanding is that in order to get intellisense to work properly with node modules, you need to include the typings of the projects that you're working on ([Link here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_intellisense)).

What I also understand is that you can have a `typings.json` file that stores all the "type definitions" and you run a `typings install` to retrieve all the typings.

This is all to get the intellisense working in vscode. What I am not sure is whether you should exclude this (`typings` folder and `typings.json`) from version control altogether?

*At the moment I think that the editor should not influence the source code structure. I'm pretty sure that you should exclude the `typings` folder. I am not sure about `typings.json`. It could be useful for vscode users, but will most likely be pointless for WebStorm/Atom/Sublime/Vim users?*

Comment: If you don't control it (in the same project), it probably doesn't belong in the same repo. You're better off with an on-site proxy or artifact server than committing your dependencies to each project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of the typings folder can easily be recreated by running `typings install`. If you have any kind of build process like webpack, browserify, gulp or similar, then you also need to have these definitions to be able to run the typescript compiler in your continuous integration system for example.

So you should commit the `typings.json` and add some `npm postinstall` scripts to automatically download the typings when you run `npm install` to be able to build your code in an automated way.

Comment: This is for es6 based projects, not for typescript based. I think that this makes sense for typescript projects though

Comment: What do you mean exactly? An automated build process? Of course this makes sense for typescript projects. We are using typescript and webpack together and it's a pretty good match. Even angular 2 now provides a tutorial on using typescript with webpack here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html. When you are using typescript and typings, you probably have npm configured for your project, right? So why not just add a postinstall script and remove the typings folder?

Comment: Or if you're using the Gitlab/Travis YML build script, you just add a line to install the typings before running tsc/webpack/gulp/whatever.